# SQL Join with data associated to dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have a simple SQL request to get aall `group departure date` and the associated `group size` (teamLength) between 2 dates but it doesn't work properly.

```sql
SELECT `groups`.`departure`, COUNT(`group_users`.`group_id`) as 'teamLength'
FROM `groups`
    INNER JOIN `group_users`
ON `groups`.`id` = `group_users`.`group_id`
  WHERE departure BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31'
```

In fact, if I have more than 1 group between the 2 dates, only 1 date will be recovered in association with the total number of teamLength.

For exemple, if I have 2 groups in the same interval with, for group 1, 2 people and for group 2, 1 people, the result will be:

[image: SQL Result]

Here are 2 screenshots of the current state of my `groups` and `group_users` tables:
[image]

[image]

Is it even possible to do what I want in only 1 SQL request ? Thanks

Comment: Tip: Have an `ON` clause to be ANSI SQL compliant and portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what jarlh commented (`JOIN` with `ON`). Don't ever group data without an explicit `GROUP BY`. I don't know why MYSQL still allows this...

Change your query to something like this and you should get the result you are looking for. Currently, the other departure dates get lost in the aggregation.

```
SELECT
    groups.departure,
    COUNT(1) as team_length
FROM
    groups
    INNER JOIN group_users
        ON groups.id = group_users.group_id
WHERE
    groups.departure BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31'
GROUP BY
    groups.departure
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a syntax issue in your query. You are missing the `ON` statement so your database could be trying to get a cartesian product since there is no join clause.

```
SELECT `groups`.`departure`, COUNT(`group_users`.`id`) as 'teamLength'
FROM `groups`
    INNER JOIN `group_users` ON `groups`.`id` = `group_users`.`group_id`
WHERE departure BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31'
GROUP BY `groups`.`departure`
```

You also are missing the `GROUP BY`clause which is not mandatory in all RDBS but it is a good practice to set it.